# If $G = R - \{0\}$ is a multiplicative group and $H = R^+$ is a multiplicative group, describe geometrically the cosets of $H$ in $G.$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $G = \mathbb{R} - \{0\}$ is a multiplicative group and $H = \mathbb{R}^+$ (the positive reals) is a multiplicative group, describe geometrically the cosets of $H$ in $G.$

How would one describe them geometrically? A coset is $Ha = aH$ (since $G$ is abelian), and it seems that a coset of $H$ is a linear map on $H.$ Something like that?

Comment: Do we have $R = \Bbb R$?

Comment: What is the meaning of $R^+$?

Comment: thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Sorry for giving the solution but this is really a matter of definition $$G=H\cup -H$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know $G,H$ are both abelian groups under multiplication, and that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Thus it is equivalent to think of either $aH$ or $Ha$. In this case,

$$aH = \{ ah \mid a \in G, h\in H \} =  \{ ah \mid a \in \Bbb R -\{ 0\}, h\in \Bbb R^+ \}$$

In light of this formulation, it becomes clear that the cosets are just scalings of $\Bbb R^+ = (0,\infty)$ by some nonzero real constant $a$.

When framed in that light, it shouldn't be hard to convince yourself $aH = H$ ($a \Bbb R^+ = \Bbb R^+$) for $a>0$, and for $a<0$ you get $-H$ ($\Bbb R^-=(-\infty,0)$) instead.

Considering now that the set of cosets of a subgroup form a partition of the original group, it should be easy to determine the cosets at this point.